# How do you calculate a statistically significant sample size based off of the total number of records? (Postgres)

Tags: sql, postgresql, amazon-redshift

Lets say I want to get a random sample of customers who have purchased from a specific department in the last year.

I want to make sure the random sample from each department is statistically significant (using the sample size formula), out of the total population of customers that have purchased from the department (if a department had 50 million customers who made a minimum of 1 purchase, the sample size required would be about 390).

I'm looking for something that looks like this:
I would end my SQL query with **ORDER BY random() LIMIT (*subquery here to determine the correct sample size*)**

How can I implement the sample size formula into a subquery that the LIMIT BY statement pulls from?

Comment: Postgres or Redshift? Although they have the same roots, they are not the same

Comment: Your random data leaves me scratching my head because I don't know your actual data... but for a random data set, just order by newid()

Comment: Maybe `random() < XXX` to do such a thing rather than `ORDER BY random() LIMIT ...`. `XXX` must be replaced by `samplesize(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM T)`. Would that make sense?

Comment: as per first comment please remove all trace of eithe redshift or postgres from your question and tags

Answer (score 0):

You can use window functions:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by department order by rand()) as seqnum,
             count(*) over (partition by department) as cnt
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum < <your formula based on department size here>;
```

I don't now what your formula is for statistical significant but you can plug it in using the department size (`cnt`) calculated in the subquery.